# Can I uppercase particular letter in string in Python?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

Lest say I have string like this:

```
string = "hello world"
```

I want to have only praticular letter uppercased so if i choose second letter my output should look like this:

```
hEllo wold
```

But if i try for example:

```
string[1].upper()
```

My output is:

```
hello world
```

And not:

```
hEllo wold
```

I dont know why...

Comment: Strings are immutable, `string[1].upper()` creates a new single character uppercased string. You could do what you want with `"".join(c.upper() if c in "eo" else c for c in string)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "my output"? `string[1].upper()` returns `'E'`.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
string[1].upper()
```

Isn't doing what you think. Sure, it uppercases the value in `string[1]`, but it returns a new string with the result! - because in Python strings are *immutable*. Now, you'd be tempted to think that this would fix it:

```
string[1] = string[1].upper()
```

... But no, this will fail because once again - strings are *immutable*. You have no choice but to create a new string, with some logic to tell which positions you want to uppercase. For example, to uppercase the value at index = 1:

```
''.join(c.upper() if i == 1 else c for i, c in enumerate(string))
```

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize only one letter of a string you have to capitalize the part of the string starting from the nth position, and assign it back to the variable:

```
string = string[:n] + string[n:].capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python Strings are not Modifiable hence the operation that you specified would not work.

In order to make this work,you can convert the string to a list and then convert a particular character to uppercase and then join the result back into a string.

```
sample_str="hello world"

sample_list=list(sample_str)                                           

sample_list[2]=sample_list[2].upper()

print(''.join(str(i) for i in sample_list))
```